# Does Scipy have techniques to import&export optimisation model files such as LP?

Tags: python, import, scipy, export, linear-programming

I am trying to manage problems from Scipy. So does Scipy provide techniques to import and export model files?

Comment: which *model files*?

Comment: ev-br: EG model files of linprog? Eg To-&-fro MPS or CPLEX LP model format?

Comment: @hhh No. I would have mentioned these in your other question and would not have lead you to cvxopt, cbc- and glpk-interfaces.

Comment: @sascha: thank you for your clarification. So alternatives contain cvxopt, CBC, glpk -- and apparently Sage and PulP as well? Gutobi/Cvxpy looks to have similar commands. Can you recite about the alternatives? Which option do you think is the best,most updated, maintained?

Comment: Pulp is write-only and i don't like that lib much. CBC and GLPK (and probably lpsolve) are the most stable probably, but CBC is hard to work with, especially from python, GLPK is much more documented, but there are tons of interfaces, some old, some new. cvxopt is very easy to use, at least for dense-data, but i'm not sure how robust it is. Some very hacky cvxopt-based approach of mps -> scipy-linprog is available [here](https://github.com/sschnug/scipy_lp_dev). Everything else is very broad, pyomo is the most powerful in general but ugly imho. cvxpy is something very diff and nice.

Comment: But in general, python lacks a bit in my opinion on this end compared to julia for example (JuMP and Convex.jl, the latter being the equivalent to cvxpy)

Comment: @sascha: how is the performance of solvers if Julia is used in the interface and potentially in the solver itself? Does there exist solvers in Julia that outperform other solver, I would expect the Julia to result into better performance? What do you think is the best free alternative and how would you deploy it? Azure ML, That, aws, other?

Comment: Solving dominates everything in 99,9% of use-cases (DCP beeing an exception, but cvxpy's DCP is C-based too). Interface-based julia is probably faster (it's not only dependent on the language, but also on algorithms and assumptions; JuMP also supports nonlinear programming and there are for example many choices on how to compute gradients), but those questions are very very broad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No as Sascha mentioned in the comment. Use other alternatives such as cvxpy/cvxopt.

Comment: I'd be interested in solving this by writing a small function to do this. I can also get around the problem at the moment, so I wanted to know if there are any news or planned developments on this issue?